# Magento 2 writing messages to a log file

Tags: magento2, logging

How do enable logging in Magento 2, i'm in development mode, i've checked file permissions on all the log files and they all have write access. Magento errors are also visible. Is there anything else i need to do?

i'm just trying to write "test" to the logs for now, i've instantiated the logger class through DI and i'm calling debug as follows:

```
$this->_logger->debug("test");
```

I've checked the debug.log and the system.log and there's nothing in there?

Comment: Check the link once http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-logging/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for print in log file

```
$this->_logger->log(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::DEBUG, "test");
```